# Query runs forever ORACLE

Tags: sql

Am trying to update the isdeleted column in one table when a record is not in the other user table .  My problem is the query l have written runs forever. how best can l write the query below.

```
update TBLG2O_REGISTER a set a."isDeleted" = '1' 
where  a."UserID" not in (select k."UserID" from TBLG2O_USER k)
```

Comment: the 2 tables contain mothan 290000 records

Comment: Which DBMS? Better to use left join

Comment: There are a couple alternative options to `not in` such as `not exists`, but you're probably just missing the appropriate keys/indices with the tables. `not in` and `not exists` are generally the fastest approaches (depending on your rdbms), but as always, you should test for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work Thank you for your help

```
 Update  TBLG2O_REGISTER a set a."isDeleted" = '1' where a."UserID" in (select p."UserID"
  from TBLG2O_REGISTER p left join TBLG2O_USER k on p."UserID" =k."UserID"  
 where k."UserID" is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is going to be database engine-specific. Performance characteristic differ wildly, across different database engines, and you failed to specify which DB server you are using.

However, subqueries are frequently MySQL's Achilles heel; I wouldn't be surprised that if this was MySQL. If so, the following approach should have better performance characteristics with MySQL:

```
update TBLG2O_REGISTER a left join TBLG20_USER k using(UserID)
set a.isDeleted = '1' where k.UserID is null;
```

Comment: am running this in Oracle it says missing key word SET